# Tagging Azure Resources from .csv

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops-services

Is there an easy way to read a .csv in a VSTS pipeline from a PowerShell script?

I have a script that can tag Azure Resources and it gets the key-value pairs from a .csv file. It works a charm when running it locally and running:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "d:\tagging\tags.csv"
```

But I'm struggling to find a way to reference the .csv in VSTS (Devops Services). I've put the .csv with the script in the same repo/folder, and I've created an Azure PowerShell script task.

I need to know what the `Import-Csv` should look like if it's in VSTS. Do I need to add additional steps so that the agent downloads the .csv when running the script?

This is the current error:

> The hosted agent can't find the file and reports "Could not find file 'D:\a_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72s1a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\3.1.6\tags.csv'.

Comment: any automation available with AzureCLI or bash scripts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you put the file in your repo in the location `/AwesomeCSV/MyCSV.csv`. Your CSV's location, from a build perspective, would be `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/AwesomeCSV/MyCSV.csv`.

So basically, pass in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/AwesomeCSV/MyCSV.csv` to the script as an argument, or reference it as an environment variable in your script as `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY`.